# Wrap devise views in a well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I am using devise. its all fun, but I need to wrap all the views in a nice span3.well and center them. I figure the code is quite simple. So here's what I want to do:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4 offset4 well">
    <h2>Sign up</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :class=>"form-horizontal") do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

      <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap this on all devise views so I want to create a structure like:

So I'd save this as a erb file and figure out some way of doing this wrapping without modifying each of devise views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create a devise layout and add the column structure to the layout?

Try creating a `devise.html.erb` in your layouts folder.

Then in the controller using it, you can call this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout 'devise'
end
```

You can even use the layout only for a specific action, or set of actions:

```
layout 'devise', only: :new # Use what you want; use an array for multiple values [:new, :show]
```

Comment: I dont' want to do this in the main layout because the structure is only for the devise views page. Am really new to ruby. Can I subclass the layout

Comment: Can I nest a layout inside another?

Comment: You don't have to do this in the main layout. You can create as many layouts as you want.